# Faye message publication delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye, private-pub

I'm using a rails application with [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com) server for pub/sub ([private_pub](http://github.com/ryanb/private_pub), faye 1.0, [puma](http://puma.io) server) on VMWare Ubuntu 12.04 instance. Everything is OK when instance is running on PC (or app deployed to the server), but on laptop every message publication from rails has 5-10 seconds delay. Instance has enough both CPU and RAM resources (for example, test suite and rails server run fast enough, just like on PC). How should I search for a bottleneck? Both faye and private_pub don't write any normal logs to analyse.

Example app sources: https://github.com/resure/private_pub_test

Comment: A have the same issue only at the server. Do you find any solutions?

Comment: Sadly, no. But you can try fork that uses Puma server, maybe that will help.